# return distinct + max in the same query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to return the results of query distinct on 2 fields.
This query work well and does what I need:

```
match(a:Assembly)
where a.SourceLocation = ""
match (a)<-[r:REFERENCES{Type: "DLL"}]-(b:Assembly)
return distinct  a.Name,r.HintPath
```

Now I need to add another field to the result. Since it is an aggregation, I am simply returning the max entry

```
match(a:Assembly)
where a.SourceLocation = ""
match (a)<-[r:REFERENCES{Type: "DLL"}]-(b:Assembly)
return distinct  (a.Name,r.HintPath),max(b.SourceLocation)
```

now, the code above doesn't work (bad syntax).
In other words, I need the to select distinct (or group by in sql) the first 2 fields combined, and the max entry of the 3rd field.

what is the equivalent in Cypher?

Comment: Please, add a sample data set and the expected result. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cypher, you can get the max value of a column using `WITH -> ORDER BY -> COLLECT()[0]`. You can also collect values into a map using using the `{key1:value1, key2:value2}` map syntax. Below is your query using the mentioned syntax's.

```
match(a:Assembly)
where a.SourceLocation = ""
match (a)<-[r:REFERENCES{Type: "DLL"}]-(b:Assembly)
with a, r, b
ORDER BY b.SourceLocation DESC
return distinct  {Name: a.Name,Hint: r.HintPath} as source, COLLECT(b.SourceLocation)[0] as location
```

Comment: thank! that mapping technique is what i was missing.